# Run script in Dockerfile to add aliases

Tags: bash, docker, alias

I have this `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM webdevops/php-apache-dev:7.2
ADD docker-bootstrap.sh /docker-bootstrap.sh
RUN /docker-bootstrap.sh
```

`docker-bootstrap.sh` looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello!!!'
cat >> ~/.bashrc <<EOT
alias hi='hello'
EOT
```

The problem is, when I run `docker build --no-cache=true .`, I see that this code is being run (I see the `hello!!!` string printed to the console), but when I bash into the Docker service and look at my `~/.bashrc` file, the alias is not there.

EDIT:

I am referencing this `Dockerfile` in a `docker-compose.yml` config file. The relevant part of this file is as follows:

```
services:
  laravel:
    container_name: laravel
    build: .
    links:
      - laravelmysql
      - testmysql
    depends_on:
      - laravelmysql
      - testmysql
    ports:
      - 8445:443
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      docker: 'true'
      WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT: '/app/public'
      WEB_NO_CACHE_PATTERN: '\.(.*)$$'
      working_dir: '/app'
```

I then use `docker exec -it laravel /bin/bash` to enter the service.

Comment: are you checking `/root/.bashrc` file when you exec into the container?

Comment: Well, I'm checking `~/.bashrc`, which is the same.

Comment: Can you add the last 5-10 lines of the `.bashrc` that you see?

Comment: I only see the commented-out default lines, not the uncommented new `alias`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit:

I stripped the `docker-compose.yml` file to below as I do not have the dependencies:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  laravel:
    container_name: laravel
    build: .
    ports:
      - 8445:443
    volumes:
      - .:/app
    environment:
      docker: 'true'
      WEB_DOCUMENT_ROOT: '/app/public'
      WEB_NO_CACHE_PATTERN: '\.(.*)$$'
      working_dir: '/app'
```

Starting the container with `docker-compose up` and `cat`ting the `/root/.bashrc` file shows that the **alias is present there.**

```
$ docker exec -it laravel bash
root@fb830bebfb0b:/#
root@fb830bebfb0b:/# cat /root/.bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.

# Note: PS1 and umask are already set in /etc/profile. You should not
# need this unless you want different defaults for root.
# PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\h:\w\$ '
# umask 022

# You may uncomment the following lines if you want `ls' to be colorized:
# export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
# eval "`dircolors`"
# alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
# alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
# alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lA'
#
# Some more alias to avoid making mistakes:
# alias rm='rm -i'
# alias cp='cp -i'
# alias mv='mv -i'
alias hi='hello'
root@fb830bebfb0b:/#
```

Few things to look for:

- You're checking the `root` user's `.bashrc` because the `RUN` in Dockerfile will execute commands as root unless specified otherwise.
- Execute permissions available to `docker-bootstrap.sh` file.
- Rebuilding the image just to be sure.

---

#### Original Answer

It works for me. Am I missing something here? Please check the following:

```
 ~/del $ cat docker-bootstrap.sh
#!/bin/bash
echo 'hello!!!'
cat >> ~/.bashrc <<EOT
alias hi='hello'
EOT
 ~/del $
 ~/del $
 ~/del $ cat Dockerfile
FROM webdevops/php-apache-dev:7.2
ADD docker-bootstrap.sh /docker-bootstrap.sh
RUN /docker-bootstrap.sh
 ~/del $
 ~/del $
 ~/del $ docker build --no-cache=true .
Sending build context to Docker daemon    126kB
Step 1/3 : FROM webdevops/php-apache-dev:7.2
 ---> 9c809301e050
Step 2/3 : ADD docker-bootstrap.sh /docker-bootstrap.sh
 ---> e90c2aa4cd44
Step 3/3 : RUN /docker-bootstrap.sh
 ---> Running in efdc2e899503
hello!!!
Removing intermediate container efdc2e899503
 ---> 567c22c68bb9
Successfully built 567c22c68bb9
 ~/del $
 ~/del $
 ~/del $ docker run -it 567c22c68bb9 -- cat /root/.bashrc
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.

# Note: PS1 and umask are already set in /etc/profile. You should not
# need this unless you want different defaults for root.
# PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\h:\w\$ '
# umask 022

# You may uncomment the following lines if you want `ls' to be colorized:
# export LS_OPTIONS='--color=auto'
# eval "`dircolors`"
# alias ls='ls $LS_OPTIONS'
# alias ll='ls $LS_OPTIONS -l'
# alias l='ls $LS_OPTIONS -lA'
#
# Some more alias to avoid making mistakes:
# alias rm='rm -i'
# alias cp='cp -i'
# alias mv='mv -i'
alias hi='hello'
```

Comment: Ok, you're not missing anything, but I'm probably missing something from my question. I'm using `docker-compose` - I think that might be the difference.

Comment: It shouldn't create a difference. `docker-compose.yml` should work in the same way as `docker run ...`. Please provide the `docker-compose.yml` file too in the question anyway to make it easier to debug.

Comment: After running `docker-compose up -d`, if you run `docker-exec -it laravel cat /root/.bashrc`, do you still see the new alias?

Comment: @GluePear yes. I still see the new alias. Also, `-d` only detaches the container from the `tty` and should have no effect in this situation.

Comment: Ok - then I am puzzled. You are using the exact same `Dockerfile`, `docker-bootstrap.sh`, and almost exactly the same `docker-compose.yml` file. Thank you for your time on this.

Comment: @GluePear Hold on, you mean `docker exec ...` or `docker-exec ...` ?

Comment: No, sorry, `docker exec`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203906/discussion-between-shubham-and-gluepear).